# python parse a json with no keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a very odd json file which I need to parse and inster into a dataframe.
This is the json file

```
{
    "data": {
        "01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj": {
            "1675348581375": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": "11991903358",
                "old": null,
                "property": "hs_object_id",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "1675348610656": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": "daily",
                "old": "",
                "property": "cohort__child_1_",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "__collections__": {}
        },
        "02b85apv47W1PRHFCXDM": {
            "1662788673128": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": null,
                "old": null,
                "property": "app_content_category_child_1_",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "1662788673129": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": null,
                "old": null,
                "property": "app_content_category_child_2_",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "__collections__": {}
        }
    }
}
```

The dataframe should end up looking like this

| id | time | author | new | old | property | sender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj | 1675348581375 | sync | 11991903358 | null | hs_object_id | hs_sync |
| 01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj | 1675348610656 | sync | daily |  | cohort__child_1_ | hs_sync |

I tried using the `json_normalize` function with no success as it didn't parse the json.
When trying to drop the json in a dataframe the values from data (`01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj` and `02b85apv47W1PRHFCXDM`) is actually being inserted into the first column but the rest of the json is being inserted as a whole string into the next column.

Comment: What do you mean by "with no keys"? Why do you think this data is "very odd"?

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. Are you using pandas?

Comment: There are plenty of keys in this data. `"data"` is a key. `"01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj"` is another key. Please be more specific about what's surprising/confusing/difficult.

Comment: I'm having issues with formatting the json to the table I included in the post. `time` isn't defined as key, therefore I need to make it key to be able to have a correct dataframe

Comment: Okay, so - do you understand how Pandas *expects* the JSON to be formatted? In your own words, *how is that different* from what you have? Therefore, what *logical steps would you need to take* in order to change it like that? If you try to write code for this, step by step, exactly where do you get stuck, and what issue do you encounter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an easy transformation.  Just enumerate through the keys.

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

data = """
{
    "data": {
        "01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj": {
            "1675348581375": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": "11991903358",
                "old": null,
                "property": "hs_object_id",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "1675348610656": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": "daily",
                "old": "",
                "property": "cohort__child_1_",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "__collections__": {}
        },
        "02b85apv47W1PRHFCXDM": {
            "1662788673128": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": null,
                "old": null,
                "property": "app_content_category_child_1_",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "1662788673129": {
                "author": "sync",
                "new": null,
                "old": null,
                "property": "app_content_category_child_2_",
                "sender": "hs_sync"
            },
            "__collections__": {}
        }
    }
}"""

data = json.loads(data)
rows = []
for key1,val1 in data['data'].items():
    for key2,val2 in val1.items():
        if key2[0] == '_':
            continue
        p = {'id':key1,'time':key2}
        p.update(val2)
        rows.append(p)

df = pd.DataFrame( rows )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     id           time author          new   old                       property   sender
0  01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj  1675348581375   sync  11991903358  None                   hs_object_id  hs_sync
1  01mSeHpsjSTHuHSGhpCj  1675348610656   sync        daily                     cohort__child_1_  hs_sync
2  02b85apv47W1PRHFCXDM  1662788673128   sync         None  None  app_content_category_child_1_  hs_sync
3  02b85apv47W1PRHFCXDM  1662788673129   sync         None  None  app_content_category_child_2_  hs_sync
```